# WebPagetest not filling in forms, gives "Navigation Error"

Tags: testing, automated-tests, synthetic, webpagetest

I'm new to WebPagetest (https://www.webpagetest.org/) and am having some trouble with login forms. I am using scripting, and can navigate to the page with the form, but it appears as though I am not correctly entering any form values, nor is the form submitting.

Here is a version of my script:

```
logData 1
navigate    https://www.example.com/secure/login
setValue    name=username   activation_test
setValue    name=password   password
submitForm  id=signInForm
//clickAndWait  id=signInBtn
//exec  document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.display = 'none';
sleep   5
block   google.com/csi
navigate    https://www.example.com/?jbhp=true
```

Of course, my first thought is to make sure that my HTML elements match, but they appear to be fine...

- *Username:*

input tabindex="1" aria-required="true" class="success required" id="username" maxlength="64" **name="username"** placeholder="Email Address or Username" type="text" value=""

- *Password:*

input tabindex="2" aria-required="true" class="success required" id="password" **name="password"** placeholder="Password" type="password" value=""

- *Form:*

form action="#" **id="signInForm"** method="post" class="form formLarge" novalidate="novalidate"

- *Submit* (verified within the form; only used when clickAndWait is uncommented)*:*

button tabindex="3" **id="signInBtn"** class="ancBtn lrg" data-track-click="sign in : sign in" type="submit"

The result page of the test shows that it navigates to the final location as though not logged in. Also, I see this as part of the results: **Step_2
(Error: Navigation Error)**. Sadly, if there is better documenting as to what specifically caused the navigation error, I have yet to find it.

Finally, if I switch from using "submitForm" to "clickAndWait" (which is commented out in the above example) the only difference in the result is that Step_2 shows a screenshot of the page rather than just an orange block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IFrames. **Stupid *IFrames***. If you find your way to my question, above, I would bet that your page has IFrames. In my case, my IFrame is coming from the same domain as the browser page -- *if this is not the case for your IFrame, I'm not sure if this will work*.

To access elements in the IFrame, I had to forget "setValue", "clickAndWait", and so on. I had to go straight to Javascript. Scripted, it looks something like these examples:

```
exec document.querySelector("iframe[id=stupidIFrameId]").contentDocument.querySelector("input[id=password]").value = 'password'

execAndWait document.querySelector("iframe[id=stupidIFrameId]").contentDocument.querySelector("button[id=signInButton]").click()
```